# RS232 Serial Communication only sending first character of string

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I'm developing a Windows Form Application with C# that needs to send a string of code (text) to a [Tanac Coil Winding machine](https://www.tanac.co.uk/english_ax2.html). It's connected to the Tanac with a 25-way RS-232C Serial Port, and to the *Windows* PC with a USB. The cable looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17YWR.png).

**The problem is that I can only send *one* character**. If I run the program it will send the first char, and then if I restart the program and try to send the string again, it doesn't send *anything*. I have to unplug the USB port and plug it in again, and then when I rerun the program, it again will send just one character and stop.

This is the code:

```
SerialPort com3 = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
com3.Handshake = Handshake.None;
com3.Open();
com3.WriteLine("12345"); // this sends just the first char
//com3.Write("12345"); // this also just sends the first char
```

Note: I have checked the SerialPort properties and they match up with the COM3 driver details.

So does anyone know what my problem could potentially be? I need to send a string of about 300 or less characters, with an average of about 4 chars between each newline char.

**EDIT:** I don't know if this helps, but the RS232C cable is connected to a RS232 Jumper Box, and the Jumper Box is connected to the RS232C port on the Tanac...

Comment: What leads you to believe that only a single character is being transmitted?  (Do you have a logic analyzer attached?)  What do you mean by "25-way"?  (do you mean DB25 or are you using a specialized 25-port serial adapter a la https://www.usbgear.com/USB2-8COM-M-CBL.html)

Comment: Additionally to what Mitch asked, what _precisely_ do you mean with "_then it locks up_". That is too vague of a description. Twentyfive people will read this, and twentyfive people will each imagine a different thing that happens. And probably none of those twentyfive people's imagination will match your reality. So....

Comment: If the device expects 8-bit data, you may want to augment with `com3.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);`, or similar.

Comment: @Mitch I can physically see it show up on the Tanac screen, but only one shows up and then the cursor just blinks waiting for more, but nothing comes... I just mean that the Serial Port has 25 pins, not 9, I guess that's maybe irrelevant information? I'm a CS person working with hardware, which I've barely studied :]

Comment: No problem.  Unless you have a bad USB to Serial adapter, the data is probably getting sent correctly.  I would hazard that the settings are not correct between the two.

Comment: Have you looked in the manual for the device about the required settings for the serial interface? What are they exactly? "_match up with the COM3 driver details._" does not sound at all like you are referring to information from the manufacturer's manual...

Comment: @elgonzo I edited the question :) What I meant was just that I can't send anything else, even with restarting the program, unless I physically unplug the USB and plug it in again. It feels like it "resets" the connection or something, allowing me to use it again...

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I'll go try that:)

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like either wrong serial settings and/or some problem with the USB/serial adapter you are using. Are you able to test with a USB/Serial adapter of a different type or make? Or perhaps even with a computer with built-in RS232 port?

Comment: @elgonzo This Tanac is ancient and the most information I could find about it is what I found here: https://www.tanac.co.uk/english_ax2.html... These USB/Serial adapters were made especially for the Tanac, many years ago by someone who previously worked here... and the supplies IT has is limited for how I can test, but we'll see what I can do..

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I tried that, but no success... earlier today I had tried different encodings but didn't have any success then, either...

Comment: Go for the low-hanging fruit(s) first. I would suggest you get yourself some terminal program that supports RS232 (i guess Putty is capable of it). Manually try different serial port settings and see what happens when you type/send some numbers over to the device. Is probably less of a hassle than tinkering with your program in an attempt to play with different serial settings. Also, if you have other software on the/another computer that works with the device, check if you can glean the correct serial settings from that program's configuration data...